# Windows Store missing in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, windows-store

I have a fresh Windows 11 copy that keeps coming without Microsoft Store.
Tried reinstalling, etc, nothing. I am, in particular, using `Microsoft Windows 11 Business` Version    `10.0.22621 Build 22621`.

I see a couple of posts out there on the topic, tried many of the suggestions, nothing.

Tried most of the steps described [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/restore-the-missing-microsoft-store-on-windows/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Settings%20app%20and,section%20and%20click%20on%20Repair.):

1. Running Windows AppStore Troubleshooter
2. Running `wsreset` (Microsoft Store Cache reset)
3. Re-registering MS Store with powershell with `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *WindowsStore* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Anyone managed to solve this ?

Comment: Please list the methods that you have tried and didn't work. There's no point in us suggesting them again.

Comment: Which edition of Windows are you installing? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After visiting innumerous resources, [this one](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-learn/the-true-fix-for-missing-windows-11-store-app/m-p/3108298) (which I hope google will index it first soon, given it's the only one that works (see comments there)) finally solves it.

In my case, the steps were not exactly the same, so here is a recap of what worked for me, but based on the [solution above](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-learn/the-true-fix-for-missing-windows-11-store-app/m-p/3108298):

1. I did not have XBox app installed, so googled for it and eventually downloaded from [here](https://aka.ms/XboxInstaller).
2. The original solution mentions a `Settings` tab, which I do not see, I guess the app was upgraded since then. Anyway, the same can be achieved by following the recommendation pop-up at the bottom - clicking at `Fix them in settings` (see screenshot below)

[image]

3. Then the following window appears. Choose to install App Store (mine is missing because I am screenshooting AFTER solving the issue). As opposed to the [original solution](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-learn/the-true-fix-for-missing-windows-11-store-app/m-p/3108298), I only installed this one, and it suffices.

[image]

That's it. You should have App Store now.

[image]